# C# - Cast a byte array to an array of struct and vice-versa (reverse)

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, struct, byte

I would like to save a Color[] to a file. To do so, I found that saving a byte array to a file using "System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes" should be very efficient.

I would like to cast my Color[] (array of struct) to a byte array into a safe way considering:

- Potential problem of little endian / big endian (I think it is impossible to happen but want to be sure)
- Having 2 differents pointer to the same memory which point to different type. Does the garbage collection will know what to do - moving objects - deleting a pointer ???

If it is possible, it would be nice to have a generic way to cast array of byte to array of any struct (T struct) and vice-versa.

If not possible, why ?

Thanks,
Eric

I think that those 2 solutions make a copy that I would like to avoid and also they both uses Marshal.PtrToStructure which is specific to structure and not to array of structure:

- [Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array)
- [How to convert a structure to a byte array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-a-structure-to-a-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: Is the only reason you want to use `byte[]` is to be able to invoke `WriteAllBytes`? There are other "safer" techniques for this such as using `BinaryWriter` or `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Today I came across an article that describes a way to do what you had wanted originally, but it involves having a mixed language project: mix of C# and C++/CLI: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33713/Generic-BinaryReader-and-BinaryWriter-Extensions

Comment: Thanks. I took a quick look but I feel a bit anxious about it. It seems it make a copy what I wanted to avoid. Also, to work with enum as bit, we can use the attribute "Flags". By using c# stream, I think we have about the same results without having to mix 2 differents languages. But thanks a lot, I will keep that in mind and will come back here if I have other byte conversion problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding Array Type Conversion**

C# as a language intentionally makes the process of flattening objects or arrays into byte arrays difficult because this approach goes against the principals of .NET strong typing. The conventional alternatives include several serialization tools which are generally seen a safer and more robust, or manual serialization coding such as `BinaryWriter`.

Having two variables of different types point to the same object in memory can only be performed if the types of the variables can be cast, implicitly or explicitly. Casting from an array of one element type to another is no trivial task: it would have to convert the internal members that keep track of things such as array length, etc.

**A simple way to write and read Color[] to file**

```
void WriteColorsToFile(string path, Color[] colors)
{
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));

    writer.Write(colors.Length);

    foreach(Color color in colors)
    {
        writer.Write(color.ToArgb());
    }

    writer.Close();
}

Color[] ReadColorsFromFile(string path)
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));

    int length = reader.ReadInt32();

    Colors[] result = new Colors[length];

    for(int n=0; n<length; n++)
    {
        result[n] = Color.FromArgb(reader.ReadInt32());
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had almost the exact solution that I will add for reference. There was some little bugs in yours. It's dull that Microsoft did not mark Color as serializable because I would have been able to use little less and probably more efficient code. But thanks you re-affirm that I was not so wrong from the track !

Answer (score 7):

Since .NET Core 2.1, yes we can! Enter `MemoryMarshal`.

We will treat our `Color[]` as a `ReadOnlySpan<Color>`. We reinterpret that as a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`. Finally, since `WriteAllBytes` has no span-based overload, we use a `FileStream` to write the span to disk.

```
var byteSpan = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(colorArray.AsSpan());
fileStream.Write(byteSpan);
```

As an interesting side note, you can also experiment with the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` as an attribute on your fields. It allows you to specify overlapping fields, effectively allowing the concept of a union.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2007/09/25/unions-in-c/) is a blog post on MSDN that illustrates this. It shows the following code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MyUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt16 myInt;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Byte byte1;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public Byte byte2;
}
```

In this example, the `UInt16` field overlaps with the two `Byte` fields.

This seems to be strongly related to what you are trying to do. It gets you very close, except for the part of writing all the bytes (especially of multiple `Color` objects) efficiently. :)

Comment: When saving to disk, beware of endianness! If you read it back in on a system with a different endianness, your colors will not be what they were. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public struct MyX
    {
        public int IntValue;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte[] Array;

        MyX(int i, int b)
        {
            IntValue = b;
            Array = new byte[3];
        }

        public MyX ToStruct(byte []ar)
        {

            byte[] data = ar;//= { 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7 }; // IntValue = 1, Array = {9,8,7}
            IntPtr ptPoit = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptPoit, data.Length);

            MyX x = (MyX)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptPoit, typeof(MyX));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptPoit);

            return x;
        }
        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyX))];
            GCHandle pinStructure = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(pinStructure.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
            finally
            {
                pinStructure.Free();
            }
        }
    }

    void function()
    {
        byte[] data = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7 }; // IntValue = 1, Array = {9,8,7}
        IntPtr ptPoit = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptPoit, data.Length);

        var x = (MyX)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptPoit, typeof(MyX));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptPoit);

        var MYstruc = x.ToStruct(data);


        Console.WriteLine("x.IntValue = {0}", x.IntValue);
        Console.WriteLine("x.Array = ({0}, {1}, {2})", x.Array[0], x.Array[1], x.Array[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pointers if you really want to copy each byte and not have a copy but the same object, similar to this:

```
var structPtr = (byte*)&yourStruct;
var size = sizeof(YourType);
var memory = new byte[size];
fixed(byte* memoryPtr = memory)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(memoryPtr + i) = *structPtr++;
    }
}
File.WriteAllBytes(path, memory);
```

I just tested this and after adding the `fixed` block and some minor corrections it looks like it is working correctly.

This is what I used to test it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new s { i = 1, j = 2 };
    var sPtr = (byte*)&a;
    var size = sizeof(s);
    var mem = new byte[size];
    fixed (byte* memPtr = mem)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            *(memPtr + i) = *sPtr++;
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes("A:\\file.txt", mem);
}

struct s
{
    internal int i;

    internal int j;
}
```

The result is the following:

[image: example]

(I manually resolved the hex bytes in the second line, only the first line was produced by the program)

Comment: I think you understand correctly but what happen if the GC decide to move the object somewhere else. I would need to have a safe handle to object which I think it is not the case in your sample. Also, I would like to cast in order to avoid any copy. An array of struct should be a consecutive bytes in memory which I think could be accessed directly in a safe way probably using some unsafe code.

Comment: @EricOuellet You can do that with the `fixed` block. If you really want to be sure GC doesn't change anything you can use `GC.SuppressFinalize(yourStruct)` to stop it from collecting your object. I think it should work like this, because I got the right result on my PC.

Comment: Probably, but you do a copy which I would like to avoid using "cast"

Comment: @EricOuellet, copying is the only way. You cannot tell the GC that the same block of memory is mapped to two different array instances (of different type). In general, you cannot "cast" from one array type to another.

Comment: SuppressFinalize does not stop the GC. It only inform it that it would not have to put the object into the finalizer queue. The GC will not have to call Finalize on it (second pass).

Comment: @Nicholas, do you have any reference to that ?

Comment: Arrays are referenced and managed object types, even arrays of value types or structs are allocated on the managed heap. Any object in the heap is type-aware, which restricts direct assignment of objects of one type to another (unless they can be cast).

Comment: @csharpler, there is 2 reasons why I can't accept your answer although I can recognize that you make great effort and very good sample. 1 - you copy the data which I wanted to avoid. 2 - your code should be compiled with /unsafe which I also wanted to avoid. If anyone can find a reference that says that I can't assign 2 different type to the same memory allocation then I vote for him.

Answer (score 0):

Working code for reference (take care, I did not need the alpha channel in my case):

```
// ************************************************************************
// If someday Microsoft make Color serializable ...
    //public static void SaveColors(Color[] colors, string path)
    //{
    //  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    //  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    //  bf.Serialize(ms, colors);
    //  byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
    //  File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
    //}

// If someday Microsoft make Color serializable ...
    //public static Colors[] LoadColors(string path)
    //{
    //  Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    //  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    //  MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    //  return (Colors[])bf.Deserialize(ms2);
    //}

    // ******************************************************************
    public static void SaveColorsToFile(Color[] colors, string path)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        int count = colors.Length;

        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, count);

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, colors[index].R);
                formatter.Serialize(stream, colors[index].G);
                formatter.Serialize(stream, colors[index].B);
            }
        }
    }

    // ******************************************************************
    public static Color[] LoadColorsFromFile(string path)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        Color[] colors;

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            int count = (int)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            colors = new Color[count];

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
                byte r = (byte)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                byte g = (byte)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                byte b = (byte)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

                colors[index] = Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
            }
        }

        return colors;
    }

    // ******************************************************************
```