# Convert Byte array to struct in VS2013 debugger

Tags: c#, struct, visual-studio-2013, type-conversion, arrays

One of the simple tricks I like to use in C# is overriding `ToString()` so that the debugger displays a developer-specified, human-readable string in the watch window.  It's really handy.

Currently, I'm debugging a 256 byte data packet that is a slight variant of ModBus/TCP.  Rather than looking at 256 array indices in the watch window, I'd like to see something like "transaction_id_high", "transaction_id_low", etc., where the mapping is 1:1 as the fields are defined within the struct.

When I just tried putting `(ModBusPacket)response_buffer` in the watch window to see what would happen, it replied with `Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'ModBusPacket'`.

Has anyone ever tried to do this and succeeded?

ModBusPacket:

```
public struct ModBusPacket
{
    char transaction_id_high;
    char transaction_id_low;
    char protocol_id_high;
    char protocol_id_low;
    char unit_id;
    char function_code;
    char sub_unit_id;
    char[] data;
}
```

The byte array is merely

```
byte[] response_buffer = new byte[256];
```

Comment: Look at the `Marshal` class.

Comment: it really helps if you show the structure of your `Struct` as well as all relevant code pertaining to your question and or issue. we can't see what you see

Comment: If your `ModBusPacket` have constructor/helper to create from the array - you can use Immediate window to construct the object (`new ModBusPacket(response_buffer)` ) and see its properties.

Comment: Assuming your `ModBusPacket` struct can be marshalled, you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array/2887#2887, then call the method in the immediate window.

Comment: Are you sure you want `char` for everything, since `char` is a 2-byte unicode character in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your packet is based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Frame_format), I would not suggest using `char` to represent bytes, since [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) in c# is a 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.  Instead I'd recommend using `byte` for 8-bit unsigned values, and `UInt16` for 16-bit unsigned values.  Then you can do:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ModBusPacket
{
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Frame_format
    // The byte order is Big-Endian (first byte contains MSB).
    public const bool IsLittleEndian = false;

    public UInt16 TransactionIdentifier;
    public UInt16 ProtocolIdentifier;
    public UInt16 Length;
    public byte UnitIdentifier;
    public byte FunctionCode;
    public byte[] Data;

    static int PostIncrement(ref int index, int inc)
    {
        int old = index;
        index += inc;
        return old;
    }

    static byte[] ElementArray(byte[] buffer, ref byte[] swapBuffer, ref int index, int size)
    {
        if (swapBuffer == null || swapBuffer.Length < size)
            Array.Resize(ref swapBuffer, size);
        Array.Copy(buffer, PostIncrement(ref index, size), swapBuffer, 0, size);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian != IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(swapBuffer);
        return swapBuffer;
    }

    public ModBusPacket(byte[] buffer)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        byte[] swapBuffer = null;

        TransactionIdentifier = (buffer.Length >= pos + 2 ? BitConverter.ToUInt16(ElementArray(buffer, ref swapBuffer, ref pos, 2), 0) : (UInt16)0);
        ProtocolIdentifier = (buffer.Length >= pos + 2 ? BitConverter.ToUInt16(ElementArray(buffer, ref swapBuffer, ref pos, 2), 0) : (UInt16)0);
        Length = (buffer.Length >= pos + 2 ? BitConverter.ToUInt16(ElementArray(buffer, ref swapBuffer, ref pos, 2), 0) : (UInt16)0);
        UnitIdentifier = (buffer.Length >= pos + 1 ? buffer[PostIncrement(ref pos, 1)] : (byte)0);
        FunctionCode = (buffer.Length >= pos + 1 ? buffer[PostIncrement(ref pos, 1)] : (byte)0);
        var length = Math.Max(buffer.Length - pos, 0);
        Data = new byte[length];
        if (length > 0)
            Array.Copy(buffer, pos, Data, 0, length);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ObjectExtensions.ToStringWithReflection(this);
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringWithReflection<T>(this T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return string.Empty;
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var fields = type.GetFields();
        var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod(true) != null);

        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        Array.ForEach(fields, (field) => values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(field.Name, field.GetValue(obj))));
        foreach (var property in properties)
            if (property.CanRead)
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj, null)));

        return values.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s, pair) => (s.Length == 0 ? s.Append("{").Append(obj.GetType().Name).Append(": ") : s.Append("; ")).Append(pair)).Append("}").ToString();
    }
}
```

Having done that, in the immediate window, you can type `buffer.ToPacket()` in the immediate window or watch window and see the formatted data.   Or you could use a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) to cast your byte array to a `ModBusPacket` if that would be more attractive.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, dbc!  What you have proposed taught me a lot.  It's almost working and I should be able to figure out the kink, which is just that BitConverter isn't converting the Length properly.  Other than that, this answer is perfect.  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh duh... the endianness for BitConverter is opposite that of my data.  Everything else probably worked because their values were 0.  :)

Comment: @Dave - I updated the answer with your feedback on endianness.