# Reading a structure send over udp in c#

Tags: c#, c++, udp

I have a client program written in c++ that sends via UDP a structure of values:

```
struct myData
{
    double n1;
    double n2;
};

myData* sendBuffer = (myData*)malloc(sizeof(mydata)); 
memcpy(sendBuffer, &mydata, sizeof(mydata));
```

However over on the server side (in c#, winforms), I use something like:

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); 
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(address, 8888);
UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

while (true)
{
    var received = newsock.Receive(ref ipep);
}
```

I understand that in C++, I could simply call `memcpy()` on the server side to obtain the structure of values automatically, but is there a way to do it in C#?

Comment: [Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array)

Comment: Use BitConverter.ToDouble().