# How do I read a struct from a Memory<byte>?

Tags: c#, struct

Is it possible to create a `struct` from a `Memory<byte>` without copying to an array? Or better yet, create a `struct` and a `Memory<byte>` that share the same managed memory?

[Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array) is tantalizingly close but not quite applicable. `Memory<T>` has a [`Pin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.pin) method, but it returns a `MemoryHandle` instead of a `GCHandle`.

XY: I'm reading and writing `Memory<byte>` from a socket, using [`BinaryPrimitives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives) on spans obtained from slices to get and set individual fields. Representing the `Memory` as a `struct` would be nicer.

Comment: You can use `MemoryMarshall.Cast` to convert a `Span<byte>` to a `Span<struct>` without copying bytes - at least, I think that is the (very poorly documented) syntax now.

Comment: Manual manipulation of memory is exceedingly unusual in C#. You typically avoid it as much as possible, and when a particular interface forces you to use it, you immediately covert it into more typical data types to work with. It appears you are violating these norms, but your justification for doing so is poorly explained. In particular, I don't understand why you don't just write some `byte[]` directly to the socket instead of manipulating memory. It's also not clear that you're actually doing the conversions I mentioned, which leaves one wondering if C# is a good language for your problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not sure it's so unusual. The .NET Core developers evidently decided that the preferred way to work with `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is to use a `Memory<byte>` instead of a `byte[]` as the buffer. The API discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17281) exists in 2.2, although it's not documented. In fact, several of the undocumented overloads of `SetBuffer` convert their argument to a `Memory<byte>` and set the `MemoryBuffer` property instead of the old `Buffer` property.

Comment: @jpmc26  In general, `Memory<byte>` and `Span<byte>` are *much* nicer to work with. The entire standard API seems to be moving toward preferring them over `byte[]`. It's just the documentation that's not keeping up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.Net Core / .Net Standard 2.1 supports [`MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=netstandard-2.1) to do a reinterpret cast on a `Span<TFrom>` to a `Span<TTo>`. You should be able to use the [`Memory<T>.Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.span?view=netcore-3.0) property to get a `Span` and then convert it to your `struct`.