# Convering byte[] to instance of a class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class:

```
public class Header
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public byte BitDepth { get; set; }
        public byte ColorType { get; set; }
        public byte CompressionMethod { get; set; }
        public byte FilterMethod { get; set; }
        public byte InterlaceMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

And array of bytes:

```
byte[] data = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Bytes directly correspond to values in class eg. Height equals 2 and BitDepth equals 3. Is there any easy way to convert this array to an object or I just have to parse individual values using BitConverter? I've tried to use serialization but it seems that classes contain more information than just field values.

Comment: If you use a struct instead of a class you could do that (but an int will of course be four bytes then). I would not recommend that path though - many pitfalls - been into many of them. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *built-in* way you could do that.

To be able to parse a byte array as an object, you could try *one* of the following:

#### Constructor

One obvious solution is using constructor which takes a byte array as parameter. It requires your byte array to be constructed in a certain way so that you read bytes from the array, convert to values of properties.

```
public Header (byte[] data)
{
    Width = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
    Height = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);
    // etc
}
```

*You might need to deal with big endian vs little endian if your code is going to run on or your data is from other OS like Unix.*

#### Indirection Struct

It is possible to read byte array as *struct* in C#:
[Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array)
You could then create a class instance from that struct. However, this might require you to have duplicate field / property definitions in both types.

#### Binary Serialization

If your byte array was a binary representation of an object in C#, you could consider binary serialization. However, binary representation is **very** slow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization

Comment: Thank you. After trying with struct I fell into endianness trap. I will choose the way with constructor, where endianness problem can be solved easily.